# Tags in Cucumber - Multiple Tags

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, tags, cucumber, testng

In Cucumber Feature file I have a Scenario called Scenario_2 with the tag: @tag1 @tag2 @tag3.
In the Runner class I use tags = "@tag2 and @tag3".
Actually there is not matching tags in the Feature file but it prints all the lines in the Scenario_2`
How it is possible?.

```
@tag1 @tag2 @tag3   
Scenario: Scenario_2
Given This is the first step in Second Scenario 
When This is the second step in Second Scenario 
Then This is the third step in Second Scenario

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features/cucumbertags_26.feature"}, 
                     glue = {"com.stepdefinitions"}, 
                     tags = "@tag2 and @tag3",
                     monochrome = true)
public class TestRunner_SamplePage 
{

}

Output:
-------
^This is the first step in Second Scenario$
^This is the second step in Second Scenario$
^This is the third step in Second Scenario$
```

Comment: Please check these links in order to better define your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Since Scenario_2 hast tags `@tag2 @tag3` and you are running `tags = "@tag2 and @tag3",`  it is normal to execute Scenario_2